# How to generate ddl for a synonym

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g, synonyms

what is the query used to generate ddl of synonym in one environment so that I can run it in the other environment

Answer (score 1):

```
SQL> create synonym sy1 for t1;

Synonym created.

SQL> select dbms_metadata.get_ddl('SYNONYM', 'SY1') from dual;

DBMS_METADATA.GET_DDL('SYNONYM','SY1')
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

  CREATE OR REPLACE EDITIONABLE SYNONYM "BP"."SY1" FOR "BP"."T1"


SQL>
```